# "I'll have take contact you two about the details later"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, have

> "I'll have take contact you two about the details later"

I read [this sentence in a manga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7au5X.jpg) and I was baffled as to what kind of grammatical function *have* is playing here. Is it an aspectual auxiliary? Is it a causative verb? Is the subject of *have* the one who takes contact?

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like a typo from a text to speech application. It might be "I'll have *to* contact you two about the details later."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the text looks as if it has a typo of omission

Comment: Maybe used the same translator as Sega. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Japan, "Take" is a common name [[ Pronunciation : taa kay ]] with current usage.

In the Manga Picture, the text is "ALL CAPITALS" ; that is why you got confused.

> "I'LL HAVE **TAKE** CONTACT YOU TWO ABOUT THE DETAILS LATER"

> The name "Take" may mean "Strong" , "Tiger" , "Mountain" , "Warrior" , "Arms" , ...

References :

> https://japanese-names.info/first_name/take/

> https://culturetour.net/japanese-last-names/take2277

Comment: Great catch!   ,,,and to think this post almost got closed as a typo.

Comment: This is a rare one where what looks like a typo is not really one. @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_

Comment: Yes, an example of how we should be very careful dealing with seemingly trivial posts, and thinking about close-votes and down-voting and their resultant  negative impact on the site.